# Block matrix 2x2 eigenvalue

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы, scipy, mathematica

Есть блок матрица Q:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

A, B, C, D квадратные sparse матрицы *n x n*.

Мне нужно задействовать эту функцию:

**scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs**

Она может принимать матрицы только 2D, если я правильно понял, а у меня Q.shape - 2×2×n×n.

Другие решатели, из **numpy** например, понимают **ndarray**, но возвращать матрицу в состояние **Q.todense** самоубийство. Съедает очень много памяти.

Что посоветуете?

Comment: матрицу какой размерности вы хотите получить на выходе из входной матрицы размерности `(2, 2, n, n)`?

Comment: Такую, чтобы её могла принять функция eigs.